# How do I register Vuetify 2.3 or any packages in a Vue 3 Project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

How to register Vuetify on a main.js when my main.js file is not using alias Vue

After importing Vuetify my all component are hidden.

dependencies :

"vue": "^3.0.0-rc.7",
"vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
"vuetify": "^2.3.9"

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

createApp(Vuetify).use(router) // I tried this but i guess this doesn't make any sense.

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Register from '../components/Register'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: Register
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

vuetify is not supported with Vue 3. You can go for vue 2. Here is the roadmap.
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/